# Ignoring Empty Elements in Dictionary List

Tags: vbscript

I am attempting to remove empty elements within a `Scripting.Dictionary` and here is what I have listed below but the "is Empty" or "is Nothing" isn't seeming to work. When the `echo` is performed, there is an empty element that I would like to be removed.

```
for each item in macDictionary
    If not objItem.MACAddress is Empty then
        wscript.echo("item=" & item)
    End if
next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [IsEmpty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cs4befa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to test for empty/not initialized variables in VBScript:

```
>> Dim NotInitialized
>> WScript.Echo CStr(IsEmpty(NotInitialized))
>>
True
```

There are other 'invisible' thingies in VBScript (zero-length string, Null, Nothing, ...) so for a more practical/tailored answer you must show how you assign elements to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

`Empty` and `Nothing` are not the same. `Nothing` is the value of an empty object variable (value assigned via `Set`), whereas `Empty` is the value of an empty "normal" variable. Only checking for `Nothing` is done with the [`Is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ake1y5wx%28v=vs.84%29) operator. To check for an `Empty` variable you have to use the [`IsEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cs4befa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function.

```vb
For Each item In macDictionary
    If Not IsEmpty(objItem.MACAddress) then
        WScript.Echo "item=" & item
    End If
Next
```

See also the VBScript [keywords documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8tbc79x%28v=vs.84%29).